# Conditional copying of files in python

Tags: python, shutil

so I'm trying to copy files to another directory if their filename starts with the same 4 digit ID as the values my list.
I'm either getting the wrong data written to the file or nothing at all.

What I have so far:

```
import shutil
import os

ok_ids = [5252,
8396,
8397,
8397,
8556,
8004,
6545,
6541,
4392,
4392,
6548,
1363,
1363,
1363,
8489,
8652,
1368,
1368]

source = os.listdir("/Users/amm/Desktop/mypath1/")
destination = "/Users/amm/Desktop/mypath2/"

for files in source:
    for x in ok_ids:
        if files[:4] == x:
            shutil.copy(files,destination)
     else:
        print("not working")
```

Sample of the files I'm trying to copy i.e. `source`

```
0000_051123_192805.txt
0000_051123_192805.txt
8642_060201_113220.txt
8652_060204_152839.txt
8652_060204_152839.txt
309-_060202_112353.txt
x104_051203_064013.txt
```

`destination` directory is blank

A few important things: `ok_ids` does not contain distinct values, but i'd like the the program to treat the list as if it does contain distinct values. for example `8397` appears in the `ok_ids` list twice and it doesnt need to be iterated over twice in the `ok_ids` loop (its a verrry long list and i dont fancy editing). `source` can often contain duplicate id's also, using the example above these are `0000`, `8652`, but the rest of the filename is different.

So in summary... if `0000` is in my `ok_ids` list and there are filenames beginning with `0000` in my `source` directory then i want to copy them into my `destination` folder.

I've looked at using `.startswith` but its not happy using a list as the argument even if i cast it to a tuple and then a str. Any help would be amazing.

**UPDATE**

Could the reason for this not working be that some of the ids contain a hyphen? and others start with a char `x` not a int value?

The first 4 values are the ID, for example these are still valid:

```
309-_060202_112353.txt
x104_051203_064013.txt
```

Comment: I think the reason it doesn't work is that `ok_ids` is a list of integers not strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import os
import shutil
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/Users/amm/Desktop/mypath1/"):
    for file in files:
        try:
            if int(file[:4]) in ok_ids:
               shutil.copy(file,destination)
        except:
            pass
```

This worked for me. The only catch is that it crawls all folders in the same directory.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
for file in source:
    for x in set(ok_ids):
        if file.startswith(str(x)):
            shutil.copy(file, destination)
```

Use `set()` to make numbers unique and `str()` to convert to string. So you can preprocess the list into a set for better performance.

Or better yet, given your naming constraints:

```
if int(file.split("_")[0]) in ok_ids:
```

---

Why your code doesn't work?

```
if files[:4] == x:
```

You're comparing a `str` with a `int`, which, intuitively, will always be False.

Comment: Hmm, its still copying the wrong data. Its copying the whole directory not just the files that start with the ID's in my list

Comment: @Abbie That doesn't make sense. Have you checked if the list contains everything?

Comment: Yep, just double checked :/

Comment: Just done a bool check, its always returning True which is what I've had before, thats why I assumed `startswith` doesnt work for this case. Baffled

Comment: I'm also getting 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'x319'
using your edit `if int(file.split("_")[0]) in ok_ids:` not all id's begin with an int (I should have mentioned)

Comment: @Abbie Turn it around; `if files[0:4] == str(x):`

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me with the slight modification of `str(x)` instead of `x`.

Try using this to see what it is doing with each file:

```
for files in source:
    for x in ok_ids:
        if files[:4] == str(x):
            print("File '{}' matched".format(files))
            break
    else:
        print("File '{}' not matched".format(files))
```

Or, alternatively, convert all the items in `ok_ids` to strings and then see what this produces:

```
ok_ids = [str(id) for id in ok_ids]
files_matched = [file for file in source if file[:4] in ok_ids]
```

Comment: thanks @Bill I have it fixed finally after mulling over it for an embarrassing 3 hours! I can only assume it was the hyphens and chars that were sometimes part of the ID, (for no good reason that I can fathom anyway). Thanks for the post

Answer (score 0):

`files[:4] == x` can never be true because `x` is an integer and `files[:4]` is a string. It *does not matter* if the string *representation of* `x` matches:

```
>>> 123 == '123'
False
```

> I've looked at using `.startswith` but its not happy using a list as the argument even if i cast it to a tuple and then a str. Any help would be amazing.

This is arguably the best way to solve the problem, but you don't just need a tuple - you need the *individual ID values* to be strings. There is no possible "cast" (they are not really casts) you can perform on `ok_ids` that affects the *elements*.

The simplest way to do that is to make a tuple in the first place, and have the elements of the tuple be strings in the first place:

```
ok_ids = (
    '5252',
    '8396',
    # ...
    '1368'
)
```

If you do not control this data, you can use a generator expression passed to `tuple` to create the tuple:

```
ok_ids = tuple(str(x) for x in ok_ids)
```